Group Supabase queries with array aggregation
If Supabase returns data from a table that contains columns parentid and childname such as (with the JavaScript API):
{
    "data": [
        {
          "parentid": 1,
          "childname": "alice"
        },
        {
          "parentid": 1,
          "childname": "bobby"
        },
        {
          "parentid": 2,
          "childname": "charlie"
        },
    ],
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "OK"
}

is it possible to create a View or SQL Function that groups rows with identical parentid into arrays, like this:
{
    "data": [
        {
          "parentid": 1,
          "children": [
              {
                  "childname": "alice"
              },
              {
                  "childname": "bobby"
              },
          ]
        },
        {
          "parentid": 2,
          "children": [
              {
                  "childname": "charlie"
              }
          ]
        },
    ],
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "OK"
}

I could form this aggregation within the client, but for efficiency I would prefer that this happens within the database.
